# Optimizarion of proc that needs remote view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two servers one is dev and other is datalake.

I have gui tool that call a stored proc `usp_get_data` on `dev` and this dev proc needs various data from `dev` tables and some data from `datalake` server using linked server. From `dev` and `inside usp_get_data` I call one proc `usp_getdata_datalake` that uses dynamic query for difrent scenarios and fetch data from linked server using `datalake.datalakedb.dbo.sp_executesql @dynamicquery`.

The problem is this dynamic query contains one view and some other tables that are really huge and slow and i am using this in loop since a lot of scenarios and calulation involved.

I want to fetch data from one slow view of `datalake` in temp table and then while using dynamic qyery i can use that temp table in dynamic qyery so it would not fetch view again and again for optimization since `existinv` method is slow but temp table is not availble in `datalake` since i created that in `dev` env before loop.

What should i do to optimize my code.

Comment: Stop using loops.

Comment: I could not because i am not allowed to change the whole structure of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would first start off by looking at the Estimated Execution Plan in SSMS:
[Getting to Estimated Execution Plan in SSMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Slqtw.gif)

From there you can see the real choke point/resource intensive blocks in your SQL proc and that can serve as your starting point for optimization:

[Sample Execution Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TePZw.gif)

Try also replacing and cursors with while loops, especially if you have a sorted dataset. In most cases, while loops will provide better performance, but not all the time.